# Group query by join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in my database:

1. applications (id, type, user_id, status_id).
2. statuses (id, name);

I want to group by type to get count of each type and then as third column I want to get how many of that count has status_id of 3

something like this:

| type | type_count | status_3_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| type1 | 4 | 2 |
| type2 | 10 | 5 |

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
select a.type, count(*) type_count, count(b.id) status_3_count
    from applications a
    join statuses b on b.id = a.status_id and b.id = 3
    group by a.type, b.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select a.type, count(*) type_count, 
       count(case when status = 3 then 1 end) status_3_count
    from applications a
    join statuses b on b.id = a.status_id and b.id = 3
Group by a.type
```

Comment: thank you. this is working. but I have another question, what if I want to get count on another table that has join with statuses table. for example descriptions table (id, name) and statuses table like this (id, name, description_id). now I want the same thing but instead of status_3_count I want description_3_count?

Comment: Then instead of status = 3 in case..when, use description_id = 3

Answer (score 1):

You can get all those information with group by from applications table. Please  try below query:

```
select type,count(*) type_count,sum(case when status_id=3 then 1 else 0 end)status_3_count
from applications 
group by type
```